# C++ Pointer does not behave as expected

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

Say I have a class similar to this.

```
class Actor {
public:
    add()
    {
        auto tmp = std::make_shared<actor>();
        actorListPtr.push_back(tmp);
    }

    static std::vector<shared_ptr<Actor>> & actorListPtr;
}
```

What I wish by this is to have a link to a separate vector, a vector with the same behavior for each individual instance of the class, referenced from another source. Any changes made in the source are to be reflected upon its pointer and vice versa. For instance.

```
std::vector<shared_ptr<Actor>> actorList;
Actor::actorListPtr = actorList;

Actor guy;
guy.add();
```

Should make the contents of `actorListPtr` equal to `actorList`. However, for me, this is not the case. What am I missing?

Comment: _"What am I missing?"_ A good beginners book.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I believe you meant to [link to the book guide](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1171191).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I wish by this is to have a link to a separate vector, a vector with the same behavior for each individual instance of the class, referenced from another source. Any changes made in the source are to be reflected upon its pointer and vice versa.

You seem to be treading on advanced C++ topics. There's a design pattern for this. It's called [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Here's one way to make it work.

```
class Actor {
   public:
      void add()
      {
         auto tmp = std::make_shared<Actor>();
         if ( actorListPtr )
         {
            actorListPtr->push_back(tmp);
         }
      }

      // Allow client code to inject a pointer to be used on subsequent
      // calls to add().
      static void setActorList(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Actor>>* newActorListPtr)
      {
         actorListPtr = newActorListPtr;
      }

   private:
      static std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Actor>>* actorListPtr;
}

// The static member variable is initialized to nullptr.
// Client code sets the value.
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Actor>>* Actor::actorListPtr = nullptr;
```

---

```
// Client code.

std::vector<shared_ptr<Actor>> actorList;
Actor::setActorList(&actorList);

Actor guy;
guy.add();
```

Comment: Your initialization of ```actorListPtr```gives me a compiler error, are you sure you don't mean ```std::vector<shared_ptr<Actor>> * Actor::actorListPtr;```?

Comment: You'll need to use `std::shared_ptr`. I'll fix the answer later.

Comment: All is now working. I do not know the validity of my question but thanks for helping me as opposed to the other guys.

Answer (score 2):

`std::make_shared<Actor>()` makes a new `Actor`, but you probably want `this`. In any case, you can't create an owning `shared_ptr` to an arbitrary, pre-existing object which already has an owner. Try instead:

```
class Actor {
public:
    static Actor & make()
    {
        auto tmp = std::make_shared<Actor>();
        actorListPtr.push_back(tmp);
        return * tmp;
    }

    static std::vector<shared_ptr<Actor>> & actorListPtr;
}

Actor & guy = Actor::make();
```

Comment: Do you mind elaborating a bit on what you mean by your first statement? I get that it is like creating an actor with the ```new``` operator, but why is that an issue?

Comment: @qwarten You're calling `guy.add()`, but `add` ignores `guy`.